# How do I type for arrays with ordered types of unknown length?

Tags: typescript

I'm using Paths (arrays of alternating numbers and strings) to specify the location of a specific Object within a structure of nested Arrays and Objects.

In each case a Path will always start and end with a number, and have any number of alternating string, number pairs between.

(i.e [number, string, number] | [number, string, number, string, number] | [number, string, number, string, number, string, number])

I know that tuples allow for ordered types, but I don't know how long my array will be, as I don't know how deep the nested structure is.

Comment: My first inclination is to say that this probably isn't possible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be warned that TypeScript can't *directly* represent such a type with accuracy.  It can be represented *indirectly* as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) constraint that you can use helper functions to require, but it adds complexity.  The best you can hope for is a type that constrains *users* of your functions to passing in *concrete values* that match this type, and then inside any implementation you widen the type to something the compiler can actually reason about easily, like `Array<string | number>`.

As a compromise, you say you don't know how long of a tuple you need, but I bet there's a reasonable maximum, right?  Do you expect these tuples to need to be dozens of elements long?  If you can think of a reasonable maximum then you can compromise with something like your example type:

```
type PickAReasonableMaximum = 
  [number, string, number] |
  [number, string, number, string, number] | 
  [number, string, number, string, number, string, number] |
  [number, string, number, string, number, string, number, string, number] | 
  [number, string, number, string, number, string, number, string, number, string, number]
// ... etc
```

But, because I like crazy type juggling, I will try to represent this by a generic constraint.  When we're done, we'll have a type like `VerifyAlternator<T>` where if `T` is a valid path type then `T` will be assignable to it, and if `T` is *not* a valid path type, then `T` will *not* be assignable to it (and in fact, `VerifyAlternator<T>` will represent a type which is either valid or closer to valid, so the user gets an error on the "bad" part).  Then you'd have a helper function like `function asAlternator<T>(x: T & VerifyAlternatorT): T;` which just returns its input, but throws up compiler warnings if the input does not validate.

First, let's come up with some type-manipulation aliases:

`Tail<T>` will takes a tuple type `T` and returns a tuple with the first element removed.  So `Tail<[1,2,3]`> should be `[2,3]`:

```
type Tail<T extends any[], D = never> =
  ((...args: T) => never) extends ((a: any, ...args: infer R) => never)
  ? R
  : D;
```

`Cons<H, T>` prepends a type `H` onto the tuple type `T`, so `Cons<1,[2,3]>` should be `[1,2,3]`:

```
type Cons<H, T extends any[]> = 
  ((h: H, ...t: T) => any) extends ((...x: infer X) => any) ? X : never;
```

`Lookup<T, K>` is the [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) `T[K]` in cases where the compiler doesn't know for sure if `K` is a key of `T`.  So `Lookup<{a: string}, "a">` is `string`, and `Lookup<{a: string}, "b">` is `never`:

```
type Lookup<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
```

`WidenToStringOrNumberTuple<T>` takes an array or tuple type `T` containing only `string | number` elements and widens any literals like `"a"` or `1` to `string` or `number`.  So `WidenToStringOrNumberTuple<[string, number, "a", 1]>` is `[string, number, string, number]`.

```
type WidenToStringOrNumberTuple<T extends (string | number)[]> = { [I in keyof T]:
  T[I] extends string ? string : T[I] extends number ? number : never
};
```

Presenting the main attraction, `VerifyAlternator<T>`.  This takes a tuple type of strings and numbers, and returns a valid (or closer-to-valid) alternating path version of `T`.  The constraints are (as I understand from your question) that the tuple must begin and end with a `number` type, it must alternate between `number` and `string`, and the tuple must have at least three elements in it (you didn't indicate that `[number]` would be okay).  Well, here goes:

```
type VerifyAlternator<T extends (string | number)[]> =
  T['length'] extends 0 | 1 ? [number, string, number] :
  { [I in keyof T]: Lookup<Cons<number, Cons<string, WidenToStringOrNumberTuple<T>>>, I> &
    (I extends keyof Tail<T> ? unknown : number)
  }
```

The first bit takes care of `[]` and `[number]` being unacceptable.  The meat of the calculation is the mapped type.  We get the `I`'th element of `Cons<number, Cons<string, WidenToStringOrNumberTuple<T>>>`.  Consider that type... it sticks an extra `[number, string, ...]` onto the beginning of the widened-to-`string`-or-`number` version of `T`.  If `T` is `["a", 1, "b", "c"]`, then it becomes `[number, string, string, number, string, string]`.  So the `I`th element of that will be: `number` for `I` is `"0"`; `string` for `I` is `"1"`, and then something like `T[I - 2]` otherwise (you can't do type level arithmetic like that).  If `I extends keyof Tail<T>` it means that `I` is *not* the last index and intersecting with `unknown` doesn't do anything (`X & unknown` is just `X`)... but if it *is* the last index, we intersect with `number`... to guarantee that a valid path ends with a `number`.

Simple, right?  Okay, maybe not.  Let's look at what happens in a few test cases:

```
type Test1 = VerifyAlternator<[1, "a", 2]>;
// type Test1 = [number, string, number]; // matches
type Test2 = VerifyAlternator<[1, "a", "b"]>;
// type Test2 = [number, string, number]; // doesn't match 
type Test3 = VerifyAlternator<[1, "a", 2, 3]>;
// type Test3 = [number, string, number, string & number]; // doesn't match
type Test4 = VerifyAlternator<[1, "a", 2, "b", 3]>;
// type Test4 = [number, string, number, string, number]; // matches
```

As you can see, for `Test1` and `Test4`, the `VerifyAlternator` version returns a compatible type to what was passed in.  But for `Test2` and `Test3` it doesn't.

So, let's use it.  Here's a helper function:

```
const asAlternator = <T extends (string | number)[]>(
  alternator: T & VerifyAlternator<T>): T => alternator;
```

And here are test cases that work and that don't work:

```
// works
const okay1 = asAlternator([1, "a", 2]);
const okay2 = asAlternator([1, "a", 2, "b", 3]);
const okay3 = asAlternator([1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c", 4, "d", 5, "e", 6,
  "f", 7, "g", 8, "h", 9, "i", 10, "j", 11, "k", 12, "l", 13, "m", 14, "n", 15,
  "o", 16, "p", 17, "q", 18, "r", 19, "s", 20, "t", 21, "u", 22, "v", 23,
  "w", 24, "x", 25, "y", 26, "z", 27]);

// errors
const bad1 = asAlternator("a"); // error! 
//                        ~~~ <-- "a" is not (string | number)[]
const bad2 = asAlternator([]); // error!
//                        ~~ <-- [] is not [number, string, number]
const bad3 = asAlternator(["a"]); // error!
//                         ~~~ <-- "a" is not number
const bad4 = asAlternator([1]); // error!
//                        ~~~ <-- [number] is not [number, string, number]
const bad5 = asAlternator([1, "a", true]); // error!
//  true is not string | number -> ~~~~
const bad6 = asAlternator([1, "a", "b", 2]); // error!
// "b" is not number ------------> ~~~
const bad7 = asAlternator([1, "a", 2, "b"]); // error!
//  "b" is not number --------------> ~~~
```

As you can see, it supports very long valid paths and rejects invalid paths.

---

So, there you go.  Type juggling success!  Is the complexity worth it to you?  If so, great.  If not, the compromises of a finite union of tuples or even just an undifferentiated array could work for you.  You'll likely have to do runtime checks or compile time assertions anyway, since the compiler only understands `VerifyAlternator<T>` for *concrete* values of `T`, not for *generic* ones, like you use inside function implementation:

```
function cannotReason<T extends (string | number)[]>(path: T & VerifyAlternator<T>) {
  path[2].toFixed(); // error! 
  // YOU know path[2] is a number, but the compiler still thinks of it as (string | number);
  // you'll need to do this:
  (path [2] as number).toFixed(); // okay
  // or even this:
  if (typeof path[2] === "string") throw new Error();
  path[2].toFixed(); // okay
}
```

---

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACglgYwNYEEBKECGBnA9gO0wCMAbCAWUwA84BbAV1qgF4oBtfRoiAJwBoo2YDzj4A5gM61uPALpQAPgFgAUFHZSZAoSPGSuvbcNESom3vIUaD-Qcb1mbR3afO2dJ-dIuLV6jk52Ll5aQZ6O3u72roEeDm6yANyqqqCQUAAqmHAkADwZUBBUwBD4ACbYUJj4IGyyAgAiLGYQAG68AHwsflAAFL0AdEOYPGLYAFyZAJQsXfhtvDNFJeWV-ZiT1SACQwMjY5OiAGa8UGgzzHMLPFM9APxnPZMNySqp4NAAwgTYuQASAgKy1KFSqNTqXWYPX6AAtJgCoLtgJMMhculslsUQWtBkMqId8CceFAABposEgGYPElQSbzdo8V7vdIAGVwuCQ9DA+QEAGlIVBeYUsasoEgICBcEdMlAHhk2Lz5HTrkyVGloAB1OBlUoZXAAZWiAHkeAA5GwZLlkfLClag3pxMSKCIyKYQ5oAb3YAEkoKIxRKpZlZOMevLvfJgaLHbKwuJaZk2BHbdiXacHm4E-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-2NVFYV6dFQMg9N4NIB9yXQ7DGl-fVANNcjLU0QgEVlTRZQRQArDREARQAbHwPTUUcEUAOw0WIEUABw0TCEUAJw0XAEUTqONEAFbi4TSDi0j1EkOL3k0bQ4uU2F+Di3TrO4OLzNhWA4tc2FACO4v82FPDiyLYXYBFDGS2FwCO4T9CO4rrSO6rrPwY7mvUVQjt02FICO4b1EAF6OxzaOYaJvA8PWT2TRjRCYGUX0wz99a9OFwO2YUPDJzwACEHlxex6g17Xdf1zXAB+zdQLkAC0bcNdRfqVHBLkOtEzptnUz3p5nUPfTV8No0XSf1mXhnVw3y8Ny37ed3UPdmLgLnmRllkJKPr1QBnZQ45Px152w4Uz4nJfz4vK9P-XzeN63HeZXAvc71ZR9g6f3Vca5x4ATW+7E57l0fs-aBr934bwXF-beu9UoHxsLIP+LlT402aBfOGV9CaNWEPQCAYDi6lwXlXDiPBiFbz7plVsNgoAdy6K-RuGCT6Z0ZjgnOU98HaQitRFGkVSEQIoaJGMiC6FuA7jI2RbcWHNwEG-deVlaE-0dOw0+HNuF41qgTfhjFUaFzvuQx+mZJHqMHnI6x8ioBsLTsfU+vMdHAP0V3QxJMRH30gZQiR38XKZhsXIhR9jVBHGgggYAcACBQAQNUPuGAcAEBQEQXA9BgAZBhF-JadoVqDwYZEdavQwASThDKbKykAq8NOh0GYHoeglIHGwJiAw6wADE4BUAgGUXoxjwHeIrj0USABNI0ABVMUcF4JQEaTCZp8hEGYCsgIIg6SOLSVibgWgYAcinCEDkEg6zRCPXBtKOAM08kuCHihV46hRKSnoL2Q58xukcVwFAeyRyJjQlmfM6Ga1Wm4A6V0npfTMYfSGexeshR2hrgHF-UMaEyx9HVEGX5TEWDMFYNRR01EZgDmTtM+Y0yACi3jem3JmaU+ZgLgXdIpUXCGeZVBAA)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), e.g.

```
type PathMember = string | number;
type Path = PathMember[];
let myPath: Path = [0, "left", 2, "alleyway"];
```

However, this doesn't enforce the start and end members to be numbers.